# Custom UserLocation annotation in MapBox

Tags: ios, mapbox

In the upcoming version 3.4 of the MapBox iOS SDK, it should be possible to create custom annotations for the user location.

In the regular Apple MapKit, we used to do this by creating an custom view in mapView: viewForAnnotation.

Is the approach to this different with MapBox? We identify the annotations by the class they are based on. I assume that we would expect this delegate method to be called also for class MGLUserLocation?

```
-(MGLAnnotationView *)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MGLAnnotation>)annotation
{
     if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MGLUserLocation class]])
     {
          NSLog(@"MGLUserLocation");  // No hit
     }

     return nil;

}
```